# Insert php variables to csv when using LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a php variable into the csv file with the data that is going to be inserted in the table.

The Table contains 3 columns, and the csv contains only 2. I want to transform the csv into a 3 column file, the third column containing this php variable for all the csv rows.

Diagrams:

Table: Field1 | Field2 | key

Original CSV file: Field1 | Field2 With 1st row: Value1, Value2 ; 2nd row: Value3, Value4

Transformed CSV file: Field1 | Field2 | key  With 1st row: Value1, Value2, $key ; 2nd row: Value3 , Value4 , $key

I was reading that could could manipulate the CSV file with OUTFILE but I've seen it's just used with SELECT and not with INSERT.

If this is way too hard, is there way for this? I just need to add the same ID for the csv rows, Thanks

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
include("mysql.php");

$key=fYt5j9oPaW; //key to be inserted into the csv file

    $db = new mysql();
    $query=$db->insert("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."' 
 INTO TABLE 2fields FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 ");
   }

 }

?>
```

Comment: How do you open the csv file?

Comment: the above code only works for inserting the existing values from the csv file @believeme I don't know what you mean by how I open the csv file.

Comment: To take values from a csv file you have to open first the file and then inserting into the database whatever you want, if I understood your question.

Comment: So the value for the 3rd column is static? Then why don’t you just load your CSV file containing the two columns into your table, and add the value for the 3rd column afterwards with `UPDATE table SET 3rdcolumn = 'foo'` …?

Comment: @CBroe because I have no way to find the values that were inserted in the table. Each time, the key generated is different. In the end there will be many rows with different keys

Comment: @believeme If I needed to look at the values I would say: SELECT * FROM Table. sorry if I did not understand well what you meant by opening the file.

Comment: Then you could go with a temporary table – load your CSV data into that, and then insert into your real table via INSERT … SELECT.

Comment: @CBroe I could do that, a temporary table is a total new concept to me in this case, But I will give it a look. Thanks

Comment: A temporary table is created like a normal one, just adding the `TEMPORARY` keyword between `CREATE` and the table name. It lives as long as your MySQL connection does, and is automatically deleted afterwards.